# Echo line to start of text file using Windows batch command?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, echo

This works to add the text `my_new_text` as the last line in all .txt files:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.txt') DO echo my_new_text>> "%%G"
```

Is there a simple edit that can be made to this command to make it add `my_new_text` as the **first line** in the file?

If I can do that then I can add the lines I need (in reverse order).

I tried things like putting `<<` instead of `>>` but that's about the limit of my abilities!

I'm not sure if echo even has this functionality?

It would be simpler in PowerShell I guess but I'd want to run that command in this same batch file.

**Trying with PowerShell using an existing file with the lines:**

I did try a Powershell command that uses an already created txt file containing the lines but that didn't work.

I ran this first as a set of standard `echo` commands to create the file:

```
echo my_1st_line>> "temp_lines.abc"
echo my_2nd_line>> "temp_lines.abc"
echo my_3rd_line>> "temp_lines.abc"
```

(Those are called ".abc" files just so they *aren't* called txt files, for this next bit!)

Then I used this PowerShell command to try to add the contents of `temp_lines.abc` to the start of all txt files:

```
Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "gci *.txt | ForEach-Object {(Add-Content $_) -Value (Get-Content 'temp_lines.abc') | Set-Content $_.FullName}"
```

That doesn't work - PowerShell doesn't add anything to the start of txt files.

It would be a lot better if this can be done just using echo but I guess it's another one where PowerShell is needed?

Comment: Given the data fits in memory, `{ (gc 'temp_new_lines'),(gc $_) | sc $_ }`

Comment: Cheers, that works. If you put it as the answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple edit that can be made to this command to make it add `my_new_text` as the **first line** in the file?

There's no way to insert data in a file in any programming or script languages because disk or tape data at the end of the file don't automatically move for you. You have to copy the data to a new file or load it into memory and save it as another file. Here's a solution in cmd

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.txt') DO (
    >  "%%G_tmp" echo my_new_text
    >> "%%G_tmp" type "%%G"
    del "%%G"
    ren "%%G_tmp" "%%G"
)
```

---

If you want to insert these 3 lines in `temp_lines.abc`

```
my_1st_line
my_2nd_line
my_3rd_line
```

to all the *.txt files then do similarly

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.txt') DO (
    >  "%%G_tmp" type temp_lines.abc
    >> "%%G_tmp" type "%%G"
    del "%%G"
    ren "%%G_tmp" "%%G"
)
```

---

[`Add-Content`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.2) in PowerShell obviously won't work because it *appends content to a specified item or file* if you've read its [man page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.2#description). And there's no PowerShell that can prepend data to a file due to the reason I said. The solution is also copy data to memory or to another file

```
ls *.txt |% { (gc temp_lines.abc, $_) | sc $_}
ls *.txt |% { $c = gc $_; cp temp_lines.abc $_; ac $_ $c }
```